# jQuery Responsive Menu, desktop function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I'm using this jQuery code to create a mobile responsive menu.

It works fine when the mobile menu is displayed. However, on a landscape oriented tablet where the menu is displaying the desktop version, the initial click of a drop-down/sub-menu instantly appears then the script is adding a display:none and instantly hiding it.

So the behavior is good for it's purpose but when the mobile menu is replaced with the desktop version the onclick feature for large touchscreen devices fails. It can be clicked a second time and the script allows for proper usage. But for user experience the need to click it twice is unacceptable.

This is for a theme where the screen size at which the menu will change from mobile to desktop may vary from site to site and I do not want to have to change it each build. So a more "universal" solution is what I'm after. Thank you.

Here is the jQuery:

```
// MOBILE NAVIGATION MENU

( function() {
var nav = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' ), button, menu;
if ( ! nav ) {
    return;
}

button = nav.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
menu   = nav.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];
if ( ! button ) {
    return;
}

// Hide button if menu is missing or empty.
if ( ! menu || ! menu.childNodes.length ) {
    button.style.display = 'none';
    return;
}

button.onclick = function() {
    if ( -1 === menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
        menu.className = 'nav-menu';
    }

    if ( -1 !== button.className.indexOf( 'toggled-on' ) ) {
        button.className = button.className.replace( ' toggled-on', '' );
        menu.className = menu.className.replace( ' toggled-on', '' );
    } else {
        button.className += ' toggled-on';
        menu.className += ' toggled-on';
    }
};
} )(jQuery);

(function(){
 jQuery('#site-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a').click(function(e){  
      e.preventDefault();
      if (jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').is(':visible')) 
{
           jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').hide(200);
      } else {
           jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').show(200);
      }
 });
});
```

The last function is what is making the mobile sub menu work properly but also breaking the desktop version for mobile devices.

PS, I have dangerously terrible JS/jQuery skills, so very clear, and precise instructions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').is(':visible')) 
{
           jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').hide(200);
      }
```

Looks like you're hiding it after it becomes visible. You need to remove that statement. `.hide()`

Comment: That solves the desktop version on mobile but now my mobile menu Button, when clicked, does not expand to show the menu. Thoughts?

Comment: The 'toggled-on' class only happens on the mobile menu when the Menu button is clicked. If there is a way to associate the sub-menu click with the 'toggled-on' class that may force some normal behavior in the desktop menu? Not sure if that is true or possible, just a thought.